# Drag scale as group

Tags: javascript

I'm building a free transform tool that behavior similar to Figma and Photoshop. So far I have figured out rotation, drag, resize from point and aspect ratio.

The issue I'm facing is when the resizer group handle is dragged the object moves too much and scale too fast. Does anyone know how to make it relative to the group parent, please see the gifs link for clarification.

Current position and dimension for single resizing

```
width: newWidth
height: newHeight

x: newPosition.left
y: newPosition.top
```

What I've tried so far is adding some distance but the value is off

```
x: newPosition.left + disnaceX * ??? 
y: newPosition.top + distanceY * ???
```

I can't disclose the working code, but the code is similar to https://github.com/daybrush/moveable/tree/master/packages/react-moveable

What I'm after is the Math logic that determines how much something should scale based on its parent size.

**Image of current implementation**
[image: Image of current implementation]

**Image of how Figma and Photoshop correctly does it**
[image: Image of how Figma and Photoshop correctly does it]

Comment: can you put the working sample?

Comment: You must apply the transformation on ALL shapes, which you should have as a list or the like

Comment: I just can't help it: _"Chuck Norris doesn't use math & geometry - math & geometry uses Chuck Norris"_

Answer (score 0):

If I take it right, you should do the following in the event listener:

1. define new size of common rectangle (use "getBoundingClientRect" function)
2. set top and left positions of each of the element by solving the proportion, i.e.:

   let newLeft = oldLeft * newCommonWidth / oldCommonWidth

   let newTop = oldTop * newCommonHeight / oldCommonHeight
3. set new sizes of each of the element by solving the same proportion, i.e.:

   let newElemWidth = oldElemWidth * newCommonWidth / oldCommonWidth

   let newElemHeight = oldElemHeight * newCommonHeight / oldCommonHeight